# Is arithmetic mathematics and can we answer questions about it?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, close-reasons, policy

Yesterday, I answered [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3697268/say-hypothetically-there-were-4-seconds-in-1-minute-instead-of-60-seconds-how) (later deleted, see below for the text) and was a little surprised when the question was closed. A user in the comments stated, "This is not mathematics. It is arithmetic. Voting to close." The question was eventually closed. However, Wikipedia defines arithmetic as

> a **branch of mathematics** that consists of the study of numbers, especially the properties of the traditional operations on them.

Furthermore, the FAQ states, "*Mathematics - Stack Exchange is for people studying mathematics at **any level** and professionals in related fields.*"

[This meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1951/is-there-a-lower-bound-to-the-level-of-the-questions-that-can-be-asked-in-here) also seems to come to a consensus that arithmetic questions are allowed on the site. And finally, the original question was not just arithmetic—it was dimensional analysis, which can get pretty tricky in certain circumstances. So can questions about arithmetic be answered on the site?

---

**The question that is discussed**

*Title: Say, hypothetically, there were 4 seconds in 1 minute instead of 60 seconds. How many seconds would 24 hours (1 day) be?*

Body:

Let 1 minute = **4 seconds**.

Let 1 hour = **60 minutes**.

Let 1 day = **24 Hours**.

How many seconds would be in **1 day**?

Comment: Yes, arithmetic is clearly mathematics, and it is very puzzling as to why the question was closed *with that particular close reason.* It's not surprising that it was closed due to the level, because that happens all the time on this site. It's true that in principle the site is for those studying mathematics at any level, but in practice lower level questions get hammered with downvotes and are closed.

Comment: I think one can make a good argument to close this post independent of the issue of "arithmetic" - the post lacks context. It's a PSQ with no explanation on why the question matters, what's interesting about it, or why the asker is having trouble with it.

Comment: @KReiser Yes, I can understand that---the user provided no context and no attempts. I'm just concerned with the comment (the close reason) of the highly reputable user in the comments.

Comment: Yes, **studying mathematics** though,  granted at any level, so first year undergraduate is fine, too. Note that if "any level" would mean anything at all, then what is the point of "professionals  in related fields"? Why would a professional in an unrelated field not be included while  the mathematics an average 10 year old is supposed to master is supposedly completely  fine?  Contrary to what is claimed in the the thread linked there is ambiguity there and imo the description as written only makes any sense if it means something else then what some want it to mean, but that's a tangent.

Comment: "Is arithmetic math and can we answer questions about it?" (title of this question):  To address the second conjuct of your title: You certainly can answer *well written questions with context and other details, that concern arithmetic.*  Was the question you answered well written with context and other details?

Comment: @amWhy No, it was not, and it should stay closed for not providing context. However, the reason for closing the question in the comments was, "This is not mathematics. It is arithmetic. Voting to close." I'm not asking for it to be reopened, I'm just concerned about that specific reason.

Comment: As I clearly stated, N.Bar, I was addressing the second conjunct of your title question: "Can we answer questions about it."  Yes you can, but only when you answer *well written questions with context and other details.*  The question you answered doesn't meet that criteria.  (You asked a conjunctive question: "Is x okay, AND is y okay?"  I commented only on the "Is y okay" portion of your title.)

Comment: As of now there are 3 reopen votes on linked question. That's probably more strange than the issue being discussed here.

Comment: @MattSamuel The phrase *at any level* must be interpreted in context of the site, where people 13 years of age or younger are prohibited from participating by the terms of service. Admittedly I would have no qualms about a 12-year-old version of Terry Tao posting here, so there's that.

Comment: Anyway, [in my opinion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16484/11619) questions that Wolfram Alpha can answer could/should be declared off-topic.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: thanks for sharing that link. What I get is that answers with routine calculations / manipulation ie dealing with run of the mill variety problems should be done away with. Believe it or not, after spending quite some time here I have found that many problems which once looked quite interesting in past have become routine now (luckily most of these get duplicated and taken care of). But yes one should reduce effort dealing with such questions.

Comment: "Mathematics is the queen of the sciences, and arithmetic the queen of mathematics."

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That's a dangerous way to close questions. Wolfram Alpha is an answer machine---that's not what people need. Question askers want to understand a concept (which is why the most upvoted answer to a question is often the one marked "hint").

Comment: "Question askers want to understand a concept."  I think most of them just want the answer.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Sure. But not all. As Benjamin Franklin (probably) said, "Better 1000 bad questions go free than one good question go to waste."

Comment: @N.Bar Agree that hints are good (for those who want to understand a concept). Such people often also form their questions to reflect that. But I disagree that such hints would be the most upvoted answers as a rule. At least the accepted answers are too often those that can be copy/pasted to a homework sheet. Some of them are even generously upvoted. Wolfram Alpha is not good for hints, which is exactly one of the reasons such questions could be closed without the quality of our site suffering.

Comment: @N.Bar Quoting Franklin here feels a bit misguided given that closed questions can be immediately edited and, if the edit cured the problem, also reopened. This is not a (criminal) court of law. Rather a game of football, where we have refs calling "offside" and whatnot. Furthermore, here the crowd can talk it over with a ref, and also overrule, when judged prudent. Much gentler. The goal of these rules is not to punish, but rather to keep the game interesting for all the parties.

Comment: IMO, arithmetic is just another word for the number theory.

Comment: @kludg I'm afraid that statement marks you as ignorant about number theory..

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen My statement is correct, but I'm afraid your statement marks you as ignorant about arithmetic.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen [Serre](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387900407) disagrees.

Comment: @user1729 The number of people in this thread equating "arithmetic" with "number theory" actually made suspect that something is "lost in translation". For the purposes of the question that initiated this thread (and hence for the purposes of this discussion) "arithmetic" is one the three Rs in US grade schools. For Serre, it is something else entirely.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I feel that I should point out that my comment, like Serre's book title, was meant in jest. I do not equate "arithmetic" with "number theory" in real life! (This brings the number of people explicitly equating these two topics here to 1, and there are no upvotes on their comments. So there is no need for despair :-) )

Comment: @user1729 Not really despairing. Just confessing that after a good night's sleep the possibility of a mistranslated term occurred to me! I guess the response fwas from someone who disproves of my sentiment re: WA-answerable questions. In other words, I reap what I sow etc.

Comment: @user1729 The famous Gauss quote "Mathematics is the queen of the sciences and arithmetic is the queen of mathematics" surely equates "arithmetic" and "number theory", and JyrkiLahtonen and his upvoters could as well state that Gauss is ignorant about number theory :)

Comment: @kludg Having had a reasonable Google, I found almost no versions of that quote with "arithmetic", instead they used number theory. Of course, the original quite was in German, and apparently "die Zahlentheorie" is the relevant topic, and Google translate translates this into "number theory".

Comment: (An alternative objection to using that quote to back up "arithmetic"="number theory" is that Gauss died over 150 years ago. Mathematics, and indeed language, has come a long way since then. Modern number theory uses ideas from every corner of mathematics which it can lay it's hands upon; from what I recall, Gauss' work didn't go far beyond modulo arithmetic and a "first course in number theory" [which was an impressive achievement at the time].)

Comment: @user1729 The German quote is ""Die Mathematik ist die Königin der Wissenschaften, und die Arithmetik ist die Königin der Mathematik." I seriously consider arithmetic and number theory as synonyms, and big progress of arithmetic (aka number theory) during last 150 years does not change anything here.

Comment: I don't think there's a clear-cut distinction between "number theory" and "arithmetic," and I concede there's a sense in which they can be identified.  And yet, I don't think they can be quite used interchangeably either.  Without further elaboration, the term "arithmetic" is likely to *connote* simple computation and related matters to many (possibly most) new readers.  In the context of this thread, confusion is unlikely, since kludg is making a point about the fields themselves, and not merely characterizing a question as one or the other (or both).  But in general, it could be confusing.

Comment: The Wikipedia plot summary for [number theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_theory) explicitly calls "arithmetic" older usage for that concept, for whatever that's worth.

Comment: @kludg well, after some serious googling the quote seems to be "Die Mathematik ist die Königin der Wissenschaften und die Zahlentheorie ist die Königin der Mathematik". Can you give a source for your quote? From what I can tell, it originates from an 1856 biography (see, for example, [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfgang_Sartorius_von_Waltershausen)). You can find the biography [here](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_h_Q5AAAAcAAJ), and I guess a committed person with enough time will be able to verify which quote is correct (the search function didn't work for me).

Comment: (Of course, bickering over the precise wording of the quote is a side issue. I disagree that arithmetic and number theory are synonymous, and I would be surprised if you could find many professional mathematicians supporting your view.)

Comment: I believe that @BrianTung is correct in noting that the modern *connotation* of the word "arithmetic", in a common American English (rather than in a relatively specialized setting) is one of grade-school computation.  As comments are limited, and text is an imperfect medium of exchange, I believe that it behooves us to read the best possible intention into the comment.  To my mind, the comment should be interpreted as "This is a grade school computation, not mathematics."  The rest is simply pedantic bickering about the precise meaning of a word in multiple contexts.

Comment: "from what I recall, Gauss' work didn't go far beyond modulo arithmetic and a 'first course in number theory'" @user1729 I suggest you refresh your memory, perhaps by having a look at what Gauss actually did. The theory of cyclotomy goes well beyond a first coourse in Number Theory, as does biquadratic reciprocity, and class numbers of quadratic fields (although presented in the context of quadratic forms, rather than number fields), for starters.

Comment: @Gerry will do.

Comment: +1 for @GerryMyerson about the mention of cyclotomy and quadratic forms. Those topics are one of primary reasons for studying Gauss' original _Disquisitiones Arithmeticae_.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The question you mentioned should be closed. The argument given for closing it is arguably prone to cause confusion and dissent though.

In our guidelines [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) it is mentioned that some context should be provided.

Some consider lack of context as a reason to close. There is a community specific close reason for just this:

> **Missing context or other details**
>
> Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

It links again to [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) (in this case a particular answer).

Thus, that this question is closed is completely expected.

However, would it follow the guidelines, the mere fact that a main part of the work to do is a relatively basic computation  would not, or at least should not, result in its direct closure.

Note that even the top-answer in the thread you invoke as justification says (my emphasis):

> If someone asks a **well-crafted question** about elementary school level mathematics that is not obviously answered by a cursory internet search and has not been asked before on this site, to me it seems clear that this should be okay.

To put it differently, yes, arithmetic question are not off-topic in general, but the specific one should still be closed as it does not follow the guidelines regarding context.

Comment: The question [has been deleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3697268/say-hypothetically-there-were-4-seconds-in-1-minute-instead-of-60-seconds-how), so only users with more than 10000 reputation points can see it. This means rank-and-file users can't see directly what was wrong with it any more.

Comment: That is indeed not ideal; I included the text in the meta-question, which seemed better than to put it in my answer. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 10):

- Why is multiplication of integers commutative?
- Why does long division work the way it does?
- Does rounding too early make the bottom-line answer wildly wrong?
- Is there a more efficient way to find greatest common divisors than Euclid's algorithm?
- How can one find the smallest number representable in two different ways as the sum of two fifth powers?
- Can the sum of two odd numbers be odd?
- Why should fractions be in lowest terms?
- After subtracting page numbers, why does one add $1$ to get the number of pages?
- If $a_1$ and $a_2$ numbers leave the same remainder when divided by $8$, and similarly for $b_1$ and $b_2$, then will $a_1 b_1$ and $a_2 b_2$ leave the same remainder when divided by $8$?
- In the fraction $\dfrac{18\times 24}{6\times5}$, shouldn't the $6$ be canceled against both the $18$ and the $24$, rather than just one of them?
- How can one convert a repeating decimal to a fraction in lowest terms?
- If a base-$10$ expansion of a number repeats, will the base-$12$ expansion repeat?

All of these are questions on arithmetic. And all are questions on mathematics. And they are appropriate questions for m.s.e.

Comment: +1 especially for the mantra of counting pages via subtraction of page numbers. I often do it to calculate the number of days passed between two dates (including both) in a month.

Comment: Great questions to ask on an interview. Even to non-mathematicians, most can be answered by deduction and will show reasoning skills. But the best answer should always be: check MathExchange :).

Comment: The one about fifth powers, "Can the sum of two odd numbers be odd?" and "If a base-10 expansion of a number repeats, will the base-12 expansion repeat?" are number theory, not arithmetic.

Comment: Many of these are ok. Some were taught to me and class mates before our 13th birthday, and I would vote to keep them out. I would also keep modular arithmetic out of this list (we have a separate tag for that), but that is just my personal point of view according to which modular arithmetic is better kept under the tag [tag:elementary-number-theory]. Like Paramanand Singh, I think the example on counting pages, even though school level, is ok for general usefulness. Mind you, all these are relatively weak questions in the sense that they are highly likely to be duplicates.

Comment: My list of good fit arithmetic questions would include the likes of [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1392505/11619) and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/7795/11619).

Comment: @RosieF [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic) > The terms arithmetic and higher arithmetic were used until the beginning of the 20th century as synonyms for number theory and are sometimes still used to refer to a wider part of number theory.

Comment: The issue is not the history of the usage of the word "arithmetic" and what meanings people used to use it for, but whether questions on arithmetic (with its present meaning) should be on math.SE.

Answer (score 0):

> "This is not mathematics. It is arithmetic. Voting to close."

I am afraid such a definition of "mathematics" is too narrow to be valid and cannot be used to justify a close vote.

As for the context business mentioned in [quid's answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31807/is-arithmetic-math-and-can-we-answer-questions-about-it#comment140925_31807) and [this user's comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31807/is-arithmetic-math-and-can-we-answer-questions-about-it#comment140925_31807), I would say that the "sin" in your mentioned question is the level of difficulties.

Some users consider relatively low-level questions are less useful for the site and thus have a much more strict standard to so such questions. Look at the *sharp* contrast between your mentioned question and this two-line linear algebra question: [Do eigenvalues depend on the choice of basis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2795340) and the [review history](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/1118727) of the latter question, which even made a conceptual mistake.

Yes, the second question may be more likely to be "useful" for future readers. But sneering a question like the first one is a clear violation of the intended scope of the site. Moreover, I don't think the first question could have been written in a different way, *within the ability* of the asker, that *could* have made the post survive:

- adding the "context" of where the question is from like "I have been staring at the clock for the whole afternoon and think that ..."?
- adding the definitions of seconds/minutes/hours from a dictionary?
- any attempt? "I don't even know how to start" since this is not even a damn homework problem.
- etc.

Context alone can hardly explain why it is hard for such questions to survive.

Comment: Yes, you are right that the question at issue is unlikely to be helpful for future visitors since it is highly localised, whereas the linked question in your answer can at least serve as a duplicate target, though I think both posts are equally badly written.

Comment: I disagree regarding the impossibility to add context within the users ability. Arguably there is no guarantee that the post would have survived even with that context, but the chances would have been improved. To ridicule the idea is unhelpful.  Things that could be done, which ought to be within the users ability: (a) make clear if the problem is given to them (assigned exercise, seen in a textbook, etc) or if they came up with it by themselves (out of idle curiosity or for a more specific reason). (b) make clear if they know how to solve the classical case.

Comment: It is not clear to me what the exact point of "Context alone can hardly explain why it is hard for such questions to survive." is. It is well-known, reasonable (in my opinion), and should even be documented somewhere (I think some, including me, wrote about it at times explciitly) that users when voting of course evaluate the question according to multiple criteria, including context, formatting, genuine interest, general applicability and potential to contribute to the site as a resource for knowledge, etc. Which criteria exactly and how they balance them will depend on the user.

Comment: Regarding scope and "is a clear violation of the intended scope of the site." As commented on the main post this is far less clear than many want to make it look. I often don't get a response to my question, but I'll try again: What is the relevance of mentioning "professionals in related fields" in the target audience when the site is supposedly clearly intended for everyone and  anything at all that might fall under the purview of mathematics? As far as I can tell there would be none. *Therefore*  "studying mathematics at any level" ought to something else than "everyone and everything."

Comment: To understand such things historical context is sometimes useful. First there was a site, MathOverflow,  for people studying mathematics *at the graduate level* and professionals *in the field.* This was complemented by a more open site for people studying mathematics *at any level* and professionals *in related fields.*  The *target audience* of the site is not everyone at all. This is no contradiction to there not being any strict cut-off on the level and that we might also accept all kinds of questions from all kinds of persons. But the *target audience* is more narrow.

Answer (score -1):

I was the one who posted the comment, and I stand by my close vote. As I see it, the question was simply "What is $4\times 60\times 24$?" And that is not mathematics, as I understand the term. I would not like to see the site cluttered up with trivia like this.

Comment: I agree that the post needed to be closed, and your close vote is not the problem.  Rather, the problem is the reason you cited for closure, which was was over-generalized, and inappropriate w.r.t. any/all arithmetic questions.  There was no reason for you to slam any/all arithmetic questions (invalidly claiming arithmetic is off-topic on math.se), some of which are not trivial.

Comment: @amWhy, just so we're on the same page: can you point me to a good question that is purely arithmetical? I promise not to vote to close it :-) (I did have a brief scan through the `arithmetic` tag, but I didn't find any purely arithmetical questions there.)

Comment: @TonyK I also agree that the post should be closed (I never said it should be reopened). I'm just concerned with the reason cited. As for a good question that's purely arithmetical, hows [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443954/faster-mental-arithmetic-with-powers-of-10)

Comment: I think *realizing* that the question is essentially "What is $4\times60\times 24$" is quite different from being able to answer "What is $4\times60\times 24$" *per se*.

Comment: Can you elaborate, @T.S, because I'm having trouble making sense of your comment.

Comment: @TonyK: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/40774) count?

Comment: @user21820: Yes, that counts, as does the link in N.Bar's comment. Both these questions are about the best way to _evaluate_ arithmetical expressions; this goes beyond simply asking us to multiply three small integers together.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108718/discussion-between-amwhy-and-tonyk).

Comment: "This is not mathematics, this is arithmetic." "This is not mathematics, this is algebra." "This is not mathematics, this is geometry." " This is not mathematics, this is analysis." One statement is as nonsensical as another.

Comment: "This is not mathematics – this is theology!" Famous quote, attributed to Gordan (quite possibly incorrectly) in response to David Hilbert's proof of Hilbert's basis theorem. https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~michael.harris/theology.pdf

Comment: @TonyK I have written many answers to purely arithmetic questions; some of them are among my favorites.  [This search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A25554+%5Barithmetic%5D) produces many that might satisfy your request, although not all will.   But in particular: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703771/
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757807/
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683774/
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376365/

Comment: @MJD: Yes indeed, those are all good questions. They ask _how to do_ arithmetic. They don't ask, effectively, _What is $4\times 60\times 24$_?

Comment: I agree with your point. I was only trying to address your request for “a good question that is purely arithmetical”.

Comment: @MJD: See my comment ("Yes, that counts...").

Comment: I thought you might like to have more than one example.

Comment: I **strongly** disagree with the (currently 2) votes to delete here! This answer explains the actions the question is about by the user who did them, and so should remain. You may not agree with their opinions, but then the standard action is to downvote it, not delete it.

Comment: I’m pretty sure that ***is*** in fact mathematics.